# Google Cloud SQL Connection Error - 403: Access Not Configured - despite having enabled the API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance via a MySQL client which requires me to connect via the Google Cloud proxy. I have followed all instructions on the [Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy?authuser=2), yet after running the command to start the proxy (using correct `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` and `PATH_TO_KEY_FILE`), I receive the following `error`.

Command :

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME \ -         credential_file=PATH_TO_KEY_FILE &
```

Error :

> couldn't connect to "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME": ensure that the account has access to "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured

I have confirmed that the Google Cloud SQL API is enabled on the console for the project, but the weird thing is my project name is not 563584335869, and I have already set the correct project name via the GC CLI to no avail. So when visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869, I see:

> The API "sqladmin.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

I also created a service account under the role Cloud SQL Client, and downloaded the private key which PATH_TO_KEY_FILE points to.

Comment: Your INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME should follow this pattern: project_id:region:instance_id (you can copy it from Cloud SQL section of the Cloud Console). Check that if 563584335869 is not your project_id

Comment: I'm getting this same weird error. Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have enabled the "Cloud SQL API" (sqladmin.googleapis.com) and not "Cloud SQL" API? (sql-component.googleapis.com)?

Can you also give some more information as to your environment? Are you running this from your local machine or are you working in Cloud Shell?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can confirm that I have enabled the "Cloud SQL API", and i'm running this from my local MacOS machine.

Comment: Did you add the correct permissions to your service account? It should have the "Cloud SQL Client" role added under the IAM page.